# Error running gitk

Tags: git, gitk

Running `gitk` from the command line, while at the top level of a Git working directory, produces the following error message, and gitk fails to open:

> `objc[1031]: Objective-C garbage collection is no longer supported.
>   /usr/local/bin/wish: line 2:  1031 Abort trap: 6           "$(dirname $0)/../../../Library/Frameworks/Tk.framework/Versions/8.5/Resources/Wish.app/Contents/MacOS/Wish" "$@"`

Additionally, the following error message pops up (see screencap below):

> **Wish quit unexpectedly.**
>   Click Reopen to open the application again. Click Report to see more detailed information and send a report to Apple.
>   Ignore | Report... | Reopen

[image: Popup error message]

How can I fix this issue?

---

OS: macOS Sierra, Version 10.12.4
Git version: 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)

Comment: Which Git version?

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen: 2.11.0 (Apple Git-81)

Answer (score 0):

Open `~/.config/git/gitk` and change

```
set geometry(state) zoomed
```

to

```
set geometry(state) normal
```

[Reference](https://www.spinics.net/lists/git/msg399040.html)